# Rspberry pi3 - linux connection issue

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh, raspberrypi

these are interfaces and wpa_supplicant.conf files after setting up wifi:

```
# interface file auto-generated by buildroot

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  pre-up /etc/network/nfs_check
  wait-delay 15

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
  post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
  wait-delay 15
iface default inet dhcp
```

### ~

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1

network={
  key_mgmt=NONE
}



# reading passphrase from stdin
network={
        ssid="ARGOSS00@"
        #psk="G@M3NN@SSA"
        psk=6de278831a5094bd1c31ce565e486416a38bcac14b2f04afc36e0392f9fd248e
}
~
```

I reconfigured Wlan0:

```
# wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure
OK
# ifup -a
ifup: interface lo already configured
udhcpc: started, v1.28.4
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: no lease, failing
ifup: interface wlan0 already configured
#
```

then, i found my raspi's ip address:

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.143  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe19:36a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:19:36:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 44  bytes 9632 (9.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 168  bytes 20005 (19.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But, I can't connect to raspi from ubuntu 16.04 using ssh!

```
sudo ssh root@192.168.31.143


ssh: connect to host 192.168.31.143 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Have you enabled root login on the pi?   Ubuntu does not have root login enabled by default.

Comment: No..  i did not ..  [ #PermitRootLogin prohibit-password]